# Нужна ли запятая после "скрипта"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

Предложение следующее:
*Забегая вперёд, заметим, что вместо всего скрипта(,) "use strict" можно поставить в начале большинства видов функций.*

Comment: @Буратино Если так, то "можно поставить" без объекта (что можно поставить?). Какое-то поломанное предложение ("use strict" — это строка, она скрипт не заменяет, не вместо).

Comment: @oleedd Да, правильно, я плохо читаю) В общем, можно проще, заменив "кот" на ЭТО. 
"Забегая вперёд, заметим, что, вместо всего скрипта, ЭТО можно поставить в начале большинства видов функций." Но зависит от значений use strict - <<"use strict" — это строка, она скрипт не заменяет, не вместо>> - не мого оценить

Comment: @Буратино, "use strict", это не "название скрипта", вы немного неправильно поняли предложение. "use strict" относится ко второй части предложения, т.е. "можно поставить в начале большинства видов функций".

Comment: @Игорь а что такое use strict на что это можно заменить, чтобы было без кавычек?

Comment: Вроде как они с английского переводили. В оригинале: *Quite soon we’re going to learn functions (a way to group commands), so let’s note in advance that "use strict" can be put at the beginning of a function.*

Comment: @oleedd итак, давайте заранее отметим, что "использовать строго" можно поместить в начало функции. - даже яша переводит с выделением запятыми.

Comment: @oleedd что значит шарить в реверсе?

Comment: @oleedd опять какие-то обрывки-угадайки. Яша - это Яндекс. Автопереводчик Яндекса переводит с запятой.

Comment: @Буратино Понял. Комментарии удалены. Сами прозвище придумали?

Comment: @oleedd нет, это общеизвестное - Яша и Гоголь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Только когда дочитаешь до конца это предложение, понимаешь, что "use strict" не относится к "всего скрипта". Предлагаю поменять порядок слов:

*Забегая вперёд, заметим, что вместо всего скрипта в начале большинства видов функций можно поставить "use strict".*

*Забегая вперёд, заметим, что в начале большинства видов функций вместо всего скрипта можно поставить "use strict".*

В общем случае запятые не нужны.

> [**ВМЕСТО (чего)**, *предлог*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_287)
>
> Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «вместо», обычно не обособляются.
>
> *Вникнем во всё это хорошенько, и вместо негодования сердце наше исполнится искренним состраданием.* А. Пушкин, Станционный смотритель.

Но запятые или даже скобки не только возможны, но и предпочтительны/необходимы, например, при такой структуре предложения:

*Забегая вперёд, заметим, что "use strict", вместо всего скрипта, можно поставить в начале большинства видов функций.*

*Забегая вперёд, заметим, что "use strict" (вместо всего скрипта) можно поставить в начале большинства видов функций.*

Comment: 1. Со скобками совсем другой смысл у предложения. Стакан (вместо полки) можно поставить на стол // Здесь смысл, что мы можем поставить или полку или стакан. А нужен смысл, где мы можем поставить или на полку или на стол. 2 На каком основании вы настаиваете на выделении запятыми в "Стул, вместо пола, можно поставить на стол"?

Comment: @user190920  1. Всё верно. Со скобками (или с запятыми) получается, что мы можем поставить на стол или стакан, или полку (так же как и со скриптами). Если хотите сказать, что стакан можно поставить или на стол, или на полку, то лучше использовать "кроме": *Стакан кроме полки можно поставить на стол*.  2.  Не пол можно поставить на стол, а стул или ещё что-то: *Вместо табуретки можно поставить стул*. // Основание (но не к вашему искусственному предложению) такое: факультативное обособление оборотов, выраженных существительными с предлогами. Для лучшего понимания и лёгкого прочтения.